# Maximum value on list field does not work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, column, site-column

This ist my code (field element):

```
<Field ID="{doesn´t matter}" Name="Percent" DisplayName="Percent" Type="Number" Decimals="2" Min="0" Max="100" Percentage="TRUE" Required="FALSE"></Field>
```

So I am wondering why the the maximum value in the SP list is 10,000 not 100. The field works just fine except of this. The values are saved too so there should be no problem.

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks und greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `Max="1"` in the field definition, it will correspond to 100%.

Value of 100 corresponds to 10,000% percent.

Comment: OMG... I am blind! I did this in two other lists, same project. But this line hooked me up. Thank you for open my eyes ^^